# How to access username and password entered into a WKWebView in Swift 3

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode, swift3, wkwebview

I am trying to build an iOS app using a WKWebView in Swift 3. The WebView loads a website from its URL. I need to be able to access the username and password that the user enters into the WebView in order to save it to UserDefaults when the user clicks the submit button. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

funcionando en xcode 12.4

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        

        let lurl:String = webView.url?.absoluteString ?? ""
        
        if (lurl.contains(pagweb+"index.php")) { 
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            var user:String = ""
            var pass:String = ""
            var rememberme: Bool = false
            
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('user').value;") { (res, error) in
                if res != nil {
                    user = res as! String
                }
            }
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pass').value;"){ (res, error) in
                if res != nil {
                    pass = res as! String
                }
            }
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('rememberme').checked;"){ (res, error) in
                if res != nil {
                    rememberme = res as! Bool
                    if rememberme {
                        defaults.set(user, forKey: "USERNAME")
                        defaults.set(pass, forKey: "PASSWORD")
                        defaults.set(true, forKey: "rememberme")
                    }else if pass.count > 7 && user.count > 0{
                        defaults.set("", forKey: "USERNAME")
                        defaults.set("", forKey: "PASSWORD")
                        defaults.set(false, forKey: "rememberme")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }



func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        
        // user - pass - rememberme
        let savedUsername = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USERNAME")
        let savedPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "PASSWORD")
        let savedrememberme = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "rememberme")
        
        if savedrememberme {
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('user').value = '"+savedUsername!+"';")
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pass').value = '"+savedPassword!+"';")
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('rememberme').checked = true;")
        }else{
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('user').value = '';")
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pass').value = '';")
            wv.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('rememberme').checked = false;")
        }
    }

}
```